# Recombine link between element

Tags: mysql

I have a simple thing to do, recombine two elements in a table with their names, based on a link.

```
CREATE TABLE element (
 id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 text varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE link (
 elem_1_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 elem_2_id int(11) NOT NULL
);
```

I want to have the text of both elements in link :

After :

```
INSERT INTO element (text) VALUES ('door');
INSERT INTO element (text) VALUES ('key');
```

door = id 1, key = id 2
And

```
INSERT INTO link (elem_1_id,elem_2_id) VALUES (1,2);
```

How can i use select to have :

| door | key |

Comment: Have a look into JOIN

Comment: how you want the result,whether in a single row or multiple rows?

Comment: I can't figure out how to do it, being the same table "element". Could you give me an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to do it with :

```
SELECT e1.text, e2.text FROM link, element e1 INNER JOIN element e2 where link.elem_1_id=e1.id and link.elem_2_id=e2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT 
    e.text 
  FROM
    element e 
    INNER JOIN link l 
      ON l.`elem_1_id` = e.id) text1,
  (SELECT 
    e.text 
  FROM
    element e 
    INNER JOIN link l 
      ON l.elem_2_id = e.id) text2 
FROM
  element e 
  INNER JOIN link l 
    ON (l.`elem_1_id` = e.id) 
    OR (l.`elem_2_id` = e.id) 
GROUP BY l.`elem_1_id` 
  OR l.`elem_2_id`
```

Comment: Here I have only 1 column : "e.text", I would like to have 2 columns, one with "e1.text" and the other "e2.text". (element 1 and 2)